# How can i read json file?

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to read json file.
But, when a read my const, it's empty..
Thanks a lot to your help

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule
    ]
})

   private url: string= './../../json/config.json';
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   const aaa = this.http.get(this.url);
   console.log('aaa', aaa)

   console.log === Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
   operator: MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
   source: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: FilterOperator}
   _isScalar: false
   __proto__: Object
```

Comment: You need to call `subscribe` on the observable

Comment: what are you trying to do? What do you mean be "read"? Why are you using http module to read a local json?

Comment: @BorisDetry, help me to read a local json ;)

Comment: He is trying to read a json file into a variable/object so he can use the data.  he is using http because he thinks that is how you do it.  that doesn't work of course, so he is asking a question.  this is a fair question to me.  i have added an answer @Romain.  best luck.

Answer (score 2):

I have consumed json files in my angular projects before.  Mostly in spec files but here is an example.  You can import (or require) your json file using its path relative to your code file.

```
import * as testData from './testing/probe.testdata.json';
```

and then consume the json data using your `testData` variable.  like this:

```
const obj = (<any>testData);
var myJsonProp = obj.PropertyName;
```

this works for me, please be aware this e.g. is in typescript.  but js works too. this would replace your call to `this.http.get(this.url)` good luck!

Comment: I try that, but i have an error

Module parse failed: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 4 while parsing near '{
        picto: true
}'

Comment: @Romain - that means your JSON file is not properly formatted JSON.

Comment: Agree with @cale_b make a very simple json file to test your consumption code with.  then you can fix any issues in the real json file.  just google for json validator and you will find online validator for your json.

Comment: FWIW the json parse error means that my answer works and you are consuming the json code.  it is just invalid as we have said.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I use a class like this:

```
export class State {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}
export class City {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public state) { }
}

export const states: State[] = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Alabama'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Alaska'
    }
...
```

Then in components:

```
import { State, states, City, cities } from '../../shared/classes/us-areas';
...
readonly states: State[] = states;
readonly cities: City[] = cities;
```

Then I can use the class:

```
console.log(this.user.cities);
console.log(this.user.states);
```

For JSON you can simply import the file or subscribe to its endpoint source and output it with Angular's JSON pipe.

```
<pre>{{newData | json}}</pre>
```

For serving JSON source data you could create a service and make a `Subject` which is subscribable from anywhere.

```
public post<T>(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("https://example.com/config.json");
}
```